# With HTML/CSS how does one overlay/position a Rect on an existing HTML grid as per my diagram

Tags: html, css

How does one add additional elements to an existing grid, noting the requirement is they may span multiple cells?

Background:

- Assume using HTML5 and CSS3
- Grid created using div's, formatting using CSS "Grid"
- Grid is already created so want to add the additional blue rectangles overlaid visually onto the grid.  The rectangles being Div's with CSS formatting to show them as a blue rectangle

[image: example of what I'm after]

Say start off with HTML/CSS per below.  What additional HTML/CSS to add say the first blue rectangle in the first row:

HTML

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="box">Item 1</div>
  <div className="box">Item 2</div>
  <div className="box">Item 3</div>
  <div className="box">Item 4</div>
  <div className="box">Item 5</div>
  <div className="box">Item 6</div>
  <div className="box">Item 7</div>
  <div className="box">Item 8</div>
  <div className="box">Item 9</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Are the blue rectangles the only "contents" of the cells, or is there other content with the blue rectangles effectively grouping them visually?  Also, do the rectangles only take up a portion of the cell's height, like the diagram, or is it a full height rectangle?  Depending on how those are answered, you may need to nest tables and <td colspan...> differently.

Comment: thanks for the responses - I did actually neglect to highlight the offset case I have also, so raised a separate question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939171/how-to-position-an-overlay-rectangle-on-a-html-css-grid-but-offset-horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a given position in the grid to be shared by 2 different elements, you need to set specific positions for both elements.

Setting the position for the blue rectangles is straighforward.
Setting the positions for the items in a generic way is a little bit more hard.

I have set this in such a generic way, but if you find the selectors too hard, you can always set the grid positions 1 by 1.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}

.overlay {
   background-color: lightblue;
   height: 70px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
#ov1 {
   grid-column: 2 / span 2;
   grid-row: 1;
}
#ov2 {
   grid-column: 1 / span 2;
   grid-row: 2;
}

.box:nth-child(3n + 1) {
   grid-column: 1;
}
.box:nth-child(3n + 2) {
   grid-column: 2;
}
.box:nth-child(3n) {
   grid-column: 3;
}
.box:nth-child(-n + 3) {
   grid-row: 1;
   background-color: lightyellow;
}

.box:nth-child(-n + 6):nth-child(n + 4) {
   grid-row: 2;
   background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Item 1</div>
  <div class="box">Item 2</div>
  <div class="box">Item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Item 5</div>
  <div class="box">Item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Item 9</div>
  <div class="overlay" id="ov1">Blue overlay</div>
  <div class="overlay" id="ov2">Blue overlay</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks - a separate question perhaps, but if I wanted to have the event I'm "overlaying" to be able to start say 20% into cell 2, and finish say 50% through cell 3 any suggestions?   I just noted the "grid-column" doesn't seem to support float, but only integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to have a fixed number of cells (a bit like a calendar) you could do something like the below:

**HTML**

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="box box1">Item 1</div>
  <div className="box box2">Item 2</div>
  <div className="box box3">Item 3</div>
  <div className="box box4">Item 4</div>
  <div className="box box5">Item 5</div>
  <div className="box box6">Item 6</div>
  <div className="box box7">Item 7</div>
  <div className="box box8">Item 8</div>
  <div className="box box9">Item 9</div>

  <div className="span span1">Blue span 1</div>
  <div className="span span2">Blue span 1</div>
  <div className="span span3">Blue span 1</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: [column1] 1fr [column2] 1fr [column3] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [row1] auto [row2] auto [row3] auto;

  display: grid;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}

.span1 {
  grid-column: column2 / span 2;
  grid-row: row1;
}

.span2 {
  grid-column: column1 / span 3;
  grid-row: row2;
}

.span3 {
  grid-column: column3;
  grid-row: row3;
}
```