# How to position an "overlay rectangle" on a HTML CSS Grid, but offset horizontally from column boundaries? (per my image)

Tags: html, css

How to position an "overlay rectangle" on a HTML CSS Grid, but offset horizontally from column boundaries? (per my image)

Background:

- Assume using HTML5 and CSS3
- Grid created using div's, formatting using CSS "Grid"
- Grid is already created so want to add the additional blue rectangles overlaid visually onto the grid.  The rectangles being Div's with CSS formatting to show them as a blue rectangle
- Let's say the blue rect has to start 20% into Item5 cell, and stop 50% into Item6 cell for example
- [I did get a good answer back here [With HTML/CSS how does one overlay/position a Rect on an existing HTML grid as per my diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930118/with-html-css-how-does-one-overlay-position-a-rect-on-an-existing-html-grid-as-p), however neglected to highlight the need I have to also have the offset]

[image]

Say start off with HTML/CSS per below.

HTML

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="box">Item 1</div>
  <div className="box">Item 2</div>
  <div className="box">Item 3</div>
  <div className="box">Item 4</div>
  <div className="box">Item 5</div>
  <div className="box">Item 6</div>
  <div className="box">Item 7</div>
  <div className="box">Item 8</div>
  <div className="box">Item 9</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `position` and `z-index` on the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a pseudo element like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}
.overlay {
  position:relative;
}
.overlay:before {
  content:"overlay";
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  right:-50%;
  top:30px;
  bottom:30px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Item 1</div>
  <div class="box">Item 2</div>
  <div class="box">Item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Item 4</div>
  <div class="box overlay">Item 5</div>
  <div class="box">Item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Item 9</div>
</div>
```

In case you need to use a div element you can do the same but you adjust the top/left/right consider the container as the reference

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  
  position:relative;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(33% + 0.2 * 33%);
  right:calc(0.5 * 33%);
  top:calc(33% + 30px);
  height:80px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Item 1</div>
  <div class="box">Item 2</div>
  <div class="box">Item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Item 5</div>
  <div class="box">Item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Item 9</div>
  
  
  <div class="overlay">oevrlay</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually when I add "draggable=true" to the overlay div I notice it doesn't drag normally?  You see a faint outside with a gradient being dragged?

Comment: @Greg in what browser?

Comment: @Greg I don't see any particular issue, can you show me the code you are using?

Comment: just out at the moment - I’ll attach it when I get home - thanks